# Can I use Firebase Auth without a database?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to add Authentication to a React Web App (typescript) and I see that "firebase/auth" could be all I need. But this is the configuration:

```
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "1:xxxxxxxxx:web:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    measurementId: "xxxxxxxxx"
  };
```

Do I need databaseURL? or storageBucket?  My intention is to JUST AUTHENTICATE using Google auth for now and match the user in my database with a google ID or whatever Firebase Auth unique id has. What are the consecuences to skip databaseURL and/or storageBucket when configuring.?

Comment: You might want to remove that last line. Recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow, and that line increases the chances your question will be closed.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen for catching that! I edited my question a bit

Answer (score 2):

All Firebase services are independent of each other and that means you can use only Authentication. The other keys in the JSON are just for identification purposes. But if you have not enabled those services from the console, they are redundant. If you remove databaseUrl, you can still use Authentication.

That being said, if you don't use Firebase Authentication then you may not be able to use some features in Firebase Databases or Storage such as authentication in security rules.